# How to add or attache a specific string to the columns of dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, rename

I have a dataframe with many columns as follows:

```
my_data:
        X,Y,Z,A,BS,D,..., Tf
```

Now,  I want to a specific string e.g., 'new' or a number from 1 to n to the columns. SO my desired dataframe should be like this:

```
my_data:            
        new_X,new_Y,new_Z,new_A,new_BS,new_D,...,new_Tf
```

Or

```
my_data:
        1_X,2_Y,3_Z,4_A,5_BS,6_D,...,7_Tf
```

Comment: You want `df.add_prefix('new_')`

Comment: Yes, it works :) Many tnx

Comment: Or `[f'{ix}_{i}' for ix,i in enumerate(df.columns)]` to enumerate them